# matrix dimension error . even both matrix are 2d

Tags: matlab

dont know why matrix multiplication is not performed . even my mtrices are 2d

```
Iout = real(ifft2(Hemphasis.*If));
```

> size of Hemphasis 615x819 double
>
> size of If 616x7388 double
>
> help me in rectifying this problem

Answer (score 4):

Your Matrices are the wrong size to use the multiplication like this.

Thank about this:

```
[a b     [e f
 c d] .*  g h]
```

The result will be:

```
[a*e b*f
 c*g d*h]
```

But what if you had:

```
[a b      [e f g
 c d] .*   h i j]
```

What will g and j be multiplied with?

They must be the same size, ie `615x819 .* 615x819`

There is more information here:

http://www.mathworks.com.au/help/matlab/ref/times.html#btx_68n

Comment: matrix multiplication is not performed like that . example is correct for vector array . but not for matrix multiplication

Comment: @sheelumishra it absolutely is because you are using `.*` which is scalar multiplication.

Comment: so can u tell me how to multiply 2-d matrix with 3d matrix

Comment: @sheelumishra that isnt what you asked in the question. You have 2 2D matrices. matrix multiplication in matlab is just '*' and is the equivalent of a dot product.

Answer (score 2):

Pad your smallest array with zeros, in order to have the same size as the largest. Even better, pad both arrays to a power of 2 size in each dimension, ifft() works better.

```
size_H=size(Hemphasis); size_I=size(If);
sz=max(size_H,size_I); % get the maximum size in each dimension
p=nextpow2(sz); % get the smallest power of 2 >= sz
sz2=2.^p; % set the proper size

Hemphasis2=zeros(sz2);
Hemphasis2(1:size_H(1),1:size_H(2))=Hemphasis;
If2=zeros(sz2);
If2(1:size_I(1),1:size_I(2))=If; % place Fourier transforms at top corner

Iout=real(ifft2(Hemphasis2.*If2));
```

Since you are filtering in the frequency domain, if the pictures are available you can find the proper size a priori. This size indicates the # of samples for the fft2 you could use, and then simply multiply and do ifft2.

```
...
sz2=2.^p;
Hemphasis=fft2(h,sz2(1),sz2(2));
If=fft2(f,sz2(1),sz2(2));
Iout=real(ifft2(Hemphasis.*If));
```

Comment: For an upvote you should provide some code and an example. Then I will supply for first glorious +1!

Comment: want to have the smallest size f0r matrix multiplication. padding with zeros will give the largest matrix size. but that large size is creating problem later in the coding. 


and would u mind telling
    `Hemphasis=fft2(h,sz2(1),sz2(2));
    If=fft2(f,sz2(1),sz2(2));`

what is h and f

Comment: h is your image and f is the filter you are trying to apply, _both in space domain_.
Padding with zeros up to a 2^p size is generally useful for fft & ifft (they are calculated faster), and it is necessary if the matrices do not have the same size. In addition, dot matrix multiplication is performed in little time, no matter the size.
If h and f are available, what I would suggest is summarised in the second box. Define the size you want (let's say your image size), do fft2 for image and filter giving this size as desired number of samples, multiply and so on.

Comment: size of image is available but size of filter .. i dont know about that whether it should be manually decided or it have some relation with image size .

Comment: It depends, but that's not the case. No matter what size, by constructing the 2d fft of the image and the filter, you should keep in mind that they must have the same size in frequency domain. That new size doesn't have to be the same as the image/filter size in space domain. So, there are two suggestions: 
1) If your image is available, construct its fft. Then, construct a filter, _the same size_ as your image fft, in frequency domain. Or if it is in space domain, fft it with the same size as the image fft.
2) If not, you must pad the small one. OR crop the large, but you may lose information